# Button is being disabled due to hidden select elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a form with three select options:

- Fit
- Colour
- Size

By default, the 'Fit' dropdown and 'Colour' dropdown are active with a default value selected (e.g. Regular Fit and Blue Colour).

There are three different 'Size' dropdowns, but only one is visible at any time depending on what is selected from the 'Fit' dropdown.

The Button is disabled if an option value="none".

**Problem**

The Button only becomes active if all three 'Size' dropdowns are altered so that their value is not "none" (this is done by selecting an initial size for Regular, and then selecting Petite and Long from the 'Fit' dropdown). Ideally, I only want the button to take into account the 'Size' dropdown that is active.

**Update**

Working jsFiddle solution provided by @nagappan below, big thanks.

https://jsfiddle.net/dodgers76/c0dvdwbz/

```
var currentSelectedVals = {'selector-fit':'','selector-color':'','selector-sizes':''};
var disableComboVals = [
{'selector-fit':'','selector-color':'','selector-sizes':'none'},
{'selector-fit':'petite','selector-color':'','selector-sizes':'10'},
{'selector-fit':'petite','selector-color':'','selector-sizes':'20'},
{'selector-fit':'petite','selector-color':'','selector-sizes':'22'},
{'selector-fit':'petite','selector-color':'','selector-sizes':'24'},
{'selector-fit':'long','selector-color':'','selector-sizes':'22'},
{'selector-fit':'long','selector-color':'','selector-sizes':'24'}
];
function checkDisableCombo() {
return $.grep(disableComboVals, function(vals){
  cnt = 0;
  $.each(vals, function(key,val) {
     console.log('comparing key val '+key+val);
     if (val === '' || val === currentSelectedVals[key]) {
         console.log('>>matched values');
         cnt = cnt + 1;
     }
  });
  if (cnt===3) {
     return true;
  }
  return false;
});
};
$(function(){
var sizeVal = 'none';


  $("select.selector-fit").on("change", function(){
    //remove active
    $("select.selector-sizes.active").removeClass("active");
    //check if select class exists. If it does then show it
    var subList = $("select.selector-sizes."+$(this).val());
    if (subList.length){
      //class exists. Show it by adding active class to it
      subList.addClass("active");
      subList.val(sizeVal);
    }
  });

  $('.selector-sizes').on('change', function() {
    sizeVal = $(this).val();
  });
});

$(function() {
  $('.selector').on('change', function() {
    var $sels = $('option.selector-sizes:selected[value="none"]');
    var isSizeSelector = jQuery.inArray( "selector-sizes",this.classList);
    currentSelectedVals[this.classList[1]] = this.value;
    console.log(currentSelectedVals);
    var result = checkDisableCombo();
    console.log(result);
    if ( result.length > 0) {
        console.log('disabled false');
        $("#Testing").attr("disabled", true);
    } else {
        $("#Testing").attr("disabled", false);
    }
  }).change();
});
```

Comment: You cannot get the object this way: `$('.selector option:selected[value="none"]')` selector is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we want to disable the button by combination of the drop down selected values. We can have a global variable to track the current selected values from three drop downs. Only we can have array of disbale combos. So whenever user select a value we cross check with disable combos and if it matches we can disable the button. Validate the combo can be done as below. Updated the jsfiddle link. [JS FIDDLE UPDATED](https://jsfiddle.net/nagappan08/gtohfLqs/4/)

```
function checkDisableCombo() {
return $.grep(disableComboVals, function(vals){
  cnt = 0;
  $.each(vals, function(key,val) {
     console.log('comparing key val '+key+val);
     if (val === '' || val === currentSelectedVals[key]) {
         console.log('>>matched values');
         cnt = cnt + 1;
     }
  });
  if (cnt===3) {
     return true;
  }
  return false;
});
```

Comment: Thanks @nagappan, this is great. There are still certain combinations that disables the button, though. For example, from initial load; Select size = 10, select fit = petite, select size = 18, select fit = regular. The button becomes disabled when a Regular in Size 18 is chosen when it's in stock. The same occurs if I choose from the start a size = 6, and then select fit = petite. Any ideas what might be conflicting?

Comment: If you select a size (console disabled false) then the button becomes active, but if the user then decides to select either a different 'Fit' or 'Colour' the button becomes inactive (console -1).

Comment: modified the code for disabling the button comobo only if size is none even if other fields are changed it will retain the disabled state. Also from the understanding the combo of regular and 18 choosen should also disable, that is also added. If you want future combos to be added there is array declared which can be used in the updated js fiddle.https://jsfiddle.net/nagappan08/gtohfLqs/4/

Comment: Thanks @nagappan, this version works perfectly! The use of an array allows me to create any combination including the colour. Thanks again.